# Exec vim in new urxvt window preserving theme

Tags: shell-script, rxvt, nvim

I want to create a simple script to launch `nvim` (not `gvim`) in separate terminal window (I'm using `urxvt` term). Currently I have:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec urxvt -hold -e "vim"
```

It seems legit and works but the problem is that vim theme is not loaded when opening the terminal (probably because `.bashrc` is not read or some other weird issues with [base16-shell](https://github.com/chriskempson/base16-shell)).

Plugins do load though which means that nvim's init file is loaded. I tried to do something like

`exec urxvt -hold -e "source <absolute_path>/.bashrc; vim"`

to force base16-shell to load the terminal theme (which might be a dependency for a vim's one) but it still doesn't work.

I feel that I'm missing something but I can't get it right. How to get this script working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the problem. It turned out that `-e` flag runs a command without actually launching *interactive* bash shell which means that bash doesn't read `.bashrc` on startup.

As `base16-shell` initializes terminal theme (which is indeed a dependency of vim's base16 theme) running a script from a `.bashrc` in the end `nvim` is launched with a default colors (as dependency is not loaded and base16-vim can't initialize properly).

So the solution is to launch interactive `bash` shell explicitly to read `.bashrc` and load base16 theme and only after that launch `nvim` (which is aliased to `vim` in my occasion).

Here is the whole script:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# -hold urxvt option is not needed as vim stays running
# -i bash option to run interactively
exec urxvt -e bash -i -c "vim"
```